# Why Java timestamp parsing is prefixing 0 in millisecond part?

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat, date

```
final String OLD_FORMAT = "mm:ss.SS";        
final String TARGET_FORMAT = "HH:mm:ss,SSS";           

String timeInputStr="00:17.20";  // input is always in mm.ss.SS m--> minutes, ss-> seconds , and SSS is decimal fraction of seconds always , not actual milliseconds 
String timeOutputStr="";
Date d=new Date();
DateFormat  formatter= new SimpleDateFormat(OLD_FORMAT); 
DateFormat nformatter= new SimpleDateFormat(TARGET_FORMAT);          
try{   
        d = formatter.parse(timeInputStr);
}
catch (ParseException e){
         System.out.println("Can't Parse date "+d + " from: " +lrcTime );
}

timeInputStr=nformatter.format(d);
System.out.println( "For Input String: " + lrcTime +  " -> Parsed date "+ formatter.format(d) +  "-> will print as to  " + timeInputStr);
return timeOutputStr;
```

It's giving me the following output:

```sh
For Input String: 00:17.20 -> Parsed date 00:17.20-> will print as to  00:00:17,020
```

But I want to parse such string as `00:00:17,200`

What am I missing?

Comment: Just as an observation it is probably a good idea to move your code to use the new (since Java 8) date API.  I guess the formatters see 20 as 20 milliseconds rather than 200 (as the old formatter only has two places), and that why when you format it to three places you are getting 020

Comment: The results you're getting are correct.  The string "00:17.20" represents "zero hours (implicit, since there are no hours specified), zero minutes, seventeen seconds, and twenty milliseconds".  You want "00:17.20" to print **00:00:17,200**, but in this case "00:17.200" would _also_ print **00:00:17,200**, which means that there is ambiguity where two entirely different timestamps end up representing the same time.  That would not be correct behavior.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead depending (1) if your string represents a duration, an amount of time, which I suspect, Use `Duration`; (2) if your string represents a time of day (a few seconds after midnight (or noon)), use `LocalTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`. All of the suggested classes are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an ambiguity that is improved in the newer date time classes:

**The old [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)**

- S = millisecond

  SS with 20 means 20 ms, hence SSS will be 020 ms.

**The newer [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)**

- S = fraction of second.

  Will give SSS = 200 ms

The rationale behind the new interpretation is that with microseconds and nanoseconds a 2 ms as `,2` does not really fit with things like `,SSSSSS` - as you remarked.

Answer (score 1):

The formatter interprets the `.20` as 20 milliseconds, not .2 seconds (which would be 200ms). To resolve this issue, you can simply add a zero to your String.

```
d = formatter.parse(lrcTime + "0");
```

Comment: this worked , thanks. Can please enlighten me reason , how can I parse milliseconds part as second's decimal fraction always ?

Comment: You could use the DateTimeFormatter instead of the SimpleDateFormat